# If $A,B$ are sets such that $A$ is a subset of $B$, such that $A \subset B$, what is the proper term for $B$'s relation with $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A,B$ are sets such that $A$ is a subset of $B$, such that $A \subset B$. In this case, I am wondering what $B$'s relation to $A$ would be formally called. I can only think of saying $B$ is subsetted by $A$, but is there a better term? Thanks.

Comment: B is a superset of A.

Comment: Possibly B contains A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that $B$ is a superset of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\subset B$ but $A\neq B$ then $A$ is called a proper subset of $B$.